# Apply replacement rules to all levels

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule

I know this question has been asked multiple times before but unfortunately it seems like I'm too dumb to understand what is really going on and how to solve this.

Anyway, I want to resubstitute certain parts of an equation but also on **all levels** of that equation. My minified problem looks like this:

```
G = 4/3 x a - 4/3 y b - z^2;
rules = {4/3 x -> r1, 4/3 y -> r2, z^2 -> r3};

t1 = ReplaceAll[G, rules]
t2 = ReplaceRepeated[G, rules]

t3 = Replace[G, rules, All]
t4 = Replace[G, rules, {0, Infinity}]
```

For completion, the `FullForm` of `G` looks like this:

```
Plus[Times[Rational[4, 3], a, x], Times[Rational[-4, 3], b, y], Times[-1, Power[z, 2]]]
```

If I understand it right, then `ReplaceAll` will replace my substitutions but only on **level 0**. `ReplaceRepeated` has the same problem and `Replace`, even when specifying `levelspec` won't work either. This is the output of the above test:

```
(* t1 *) a r1 - r3 - (4 b y)/3
(* t2 *) a r1 - r3 - (4 b y)/3
(* t3 *) -r3 + (4 a x)/3 - (4 b y)/3
(* t4 *) -r3 + (4 a x)/3 - (4 b y)/3
```

I can see that in the second term (`4/3 y`) can't be replaced because *Mathematica* treats it as `Times[Rational[-4, 3], b, y]` and the `-` does not correspond to the replacement rule. I have no clue why both cases of `Replace` don't work at all...

Is there a way to apply these replacement rules to **any level** of the equation? Can someone explain me what is going on here?

Comment: "If I understood right then ReplaceAll will replace my substitutions but only on level 0. " - a good place to verify this is documentation for `ReplaceAll`: "ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts."

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't really about specifying the levels at which the various replacement function do their work. It really about formulating the right replacement rules. `ReplaceAll` is fine your task. One approach is to apply more abstract replacement rules.

```
exp = 4/3 x a - 4/3 y b - z^2;
rules = {_Rational x -> r1, _Rational y -> r2, z^2 -> r3};
exp /. rules
```

> `a r1 + b r2 - r3`

If, for some reason, you need to be specific about the rational coefficient being 4/3, then you can use

```
coef = (4/3 | -4/3);
rules = {coef x -> r1, coef y -> r2, z^2 -> r3};
```

This extra fussiness comes about because the Wolfram Language doesn't use a subtraction function internally and changes all subtraction into addition.